# How to make a reactive RESTEasy API more resilient available denial-of-service

Tags: quarkus

I've got an API in use today where resource limits are well tuned for typical traffic plus a fair bit extra for bursts of traffic. This API works well during most days, but occasionally one authorized user floods the API with a ton of concurrent requests (thousands). This unusual usage pattern causes limits to be hit (ex. running out of connection pool space) resulting in HTTP 500s for new concurrent requests until traffic dies back down. Some of these limits could be stretched through configuration at the cost of memory but it would be fairer to add per-user limits to the API to assure that a single user doesn't stave the system of resources.

I'm aware that rate limiting and concurrency limiting are common approaches for solving this problem of denial-of-service. I also found a great [Quarkus extension for providing common resiliency patterns](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-fault-tolerance) out of the box. The problem is that these patterns appear to be scoped to the application and not to the user. Using the `@RateLimit` or `@Bulkhead` annotations as-is in my API would still result in denial-of-service since a single user would just take all of the capacity provided by these limits and result in immediate errors for other users making requests at the same time. It looks like there is a [programmatic API](https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-fault-tolerance/6.2.6/reference/programmatic-api.html) available so maybe a custom limiter could be built into the request pipeline but that could be tricky to get right.

Am I missing an obvious out of the box solution for concurrent limiting of a Quarkus RESTEasy API? If there isn't an out of the box solution, is there a straight-forward way to extend the fault tolerance exception to be user-scoped or a small piece of RESTEasy middleware that could be written? Is there problem more often solved upstream in something like a load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed all the stateful fault tolerance strategies (`@CircuitBreaker`, `@Bulkhead`, `@RateLimit`) are global (singleton), there's no fine-grained scoping out of the box (yet -- I'd welcome any comments on https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-fault-tolerance/issues/438). But you've correctly identified the programmatic API as a possible solution. With that, you can implement custom scoping fairly easily.

The idea would be to have a `ConcurrentMap<SomeIdentifier, FaultTolerance<?>>` on the entrypoint to the API you need to guard. If you need to guard the entire application, you can register a handler on the Vert.x Web router that underpins all the REST resources (see https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#using-the-vert-x-web-router). If you need to guard only some REST resources, you can put the map into the resource class, or to some utility class.

The key of the map is the important part, and it's the part you need to provide on your own. (This is hard to make generic, which is why the issue mentioned above is still open.) If you figure out the identifier to use for scoping, the rest is straightforward: the value is just a `FaultTolerance` instance configured with a bulkhead or a rate limit, and you look it up from the map using `computeIfAbsent()`.

Other than that, rate limiting on a load balancer (or API gateway) are indeed common solutions.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try later. I tried doing something similar with RESTEasy filters/interceptors and ran into issues during testing (not all intercepted requests had intercepted responses leading to lockouts of users). The Vertx filters are a new angle that seem worth a shot.